# Can Cross-Site Scripting happen in mobile Applications?

Tags: android, ios, security, playframework

I can edit JavaScript and HTML to modify data which is going to server in web, which cause many things [Can someone edit javascript file offline to run malicious code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253166/can-someone-edit-javascript-file-offline-to-run-malicious-code/21253282#21253282)

But I want to know is it possible in the case of mobile Applications?

> Simply can Cross-Site Scripting happen in mobile Applications?

**I have applied SSH and I have applied session in server, is it not enough?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can which is why you need to guard against crafted input on the server.

A simple case would be a post of a form with data that should be numeric. If the validation was only client side, your server would die if someone crafted a response, which is why any validations should always be implemented on server.

Comment: i have applied `ssh` and i have applied `session` in server , did it is not enough?

Comment: How can I know from here? You need to look at penetration testing.

Answer (score 0):

The Mobile application servers can be prone to hacking and malicious request attacks as the requests can be modified and sent during the transmission. Simple but not much effective way is to encrypt the response generated by the application before the generation of the actual response/request or End to End encryption this might give security against the sniffing attacks.

For details refer : http://polyarista.tripod.com/

Answer (score 0):

As long as the attacker cannot add his own piece of Javascript code, I think you are safe. Applying SSH and session in server might save you, but you might want to run some penetration tests to be sure.